# Does Arthur Fleck dye his hair red?

Tags: plot-explanation, joker

I’m badly colorblind and sometimes miss cues in movies if they’re based on color. In the recent movie “Joker,” Arthur Fleck in a brief scene seems to be treating (and cutting?) his hair. Am I correct in guessing he is dyeing his hair red?

Comment: Nope, it's green.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

He dyes his hair green to reflect the classic Joker look.

Comment: I had to google to check — didn’t know until now that the Joker has green hair. I always assumed it was red.